# Reading zipped JSON files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I downloaded the 2015 adverse drug events data from openFDA and I want to run some analysis with Python.

I cannot get the JSON decoding to work.

I am able to find code snippets for gzip but not for plain zip files.

The error message I get is:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

The JSON files are large. Is `jsonstreamer`, `ijson`, or another library the recommended tool?

The JSON file looks like this (after manual unzip):

```
{
  "meta": {
    "last_updated": "2016-11-18",
    "terms": "https://open.fda.gov/terms/",
    "results": {
      "skip": 0,
      "total": 304100,
      "limit": 25000
    },
    "license": "https://open.fda.gov/license/",
    "disclaimer": "Do not rely on openFDA to make decisions regarding medical care. While we make every effort to ensure that data is accurate, you should assume all results are unvalidated. We may limit or otherwise restrict your access to the API in line with our Terms of Service."
  },
```

This is my code:

```
import json  
import zipfile  

d = None  
data = None  
with zipfile.ZipFile("./data/drug-event-Q4-0001-of-0013.json.zip", "r") as z:
   for filename in z.namelist():  
      print(filename)  
      with z.open(filename) as f:  
         data = f.read()  
         d = json.loads(data)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The data you read from the zipfile are bytes. The Json decoder wants text instead. So; as usual for this kind of issues, you'll have to *decode* the bytes into a string before feeding it to the json module.

I'm assuming the json files are saved in UTF-8 encoding so this will do the trick:

```
d = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Change the character encoding accordingly if your json files are in a different encoding.

Regarding your second question: how large is 'large'?

Comment: Thank you, that worked and feeling a bit chagrined that I missed that, especially with a rather obvious error  message. My largest files is around 400MB

Comment: 400 Mb unzipped json or 400 Mb zipped source file? If the latter, the actual json file in it could very well be too large for your computer's memory and then a streaming json processor is certainly something to investigate

Comment: Also depending on what analysis you want to do with it, storing it in a document database such as mongodb might be something to look at as well. That allows you to query the json data in various ways (selections on properties, projection of attributes, sorting and aggregations...). MongoDb can directly import json data I believe using the mongoimport tool

Comment: Yes, I agree. I think I am going to start with the analysis on a smaller subset and then add the database etc. Thank you for the suggestion of MongoDB, we use MongoDB, but I haven't explored it much.